# My intervals don't stop immediately after clearInterval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, setinterval, clearinterval

I have set a repeating interval to check updates to an API with setInterval in JavaScript. I have included a maximum number of iterations to prevent an infinite loop. However, when the maximum is reached, the interval will repeat a random number of extra times. It seems that if I set the interval number lower, the number of 'overshoots' increases.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this 'known' behaviour?

```
RpcService.request('ping.set').then(function(res) {
  function myFunction() {
    var i = 0;
    var x = setInterval(function () {
      RpcService.request('ping.get').then(function(res) {
        $scope.ping = res.output;
        if (res.done === true || i >= 20) { // temporarily implemented to prevent an infinite loop
          clearInterval(x);
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('timeOut ready')
          }, 500);
          $scope.buttonVisibility = [0,1,1];
          $scope.buttonDisabled = [0,0,0];
        }
        i++;
        });
    }, 200);
  }
  myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Your interval stops sending requests, but the requests that were already sent are still resolving.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Okay. That kinda makes sense to me...